# Define concrete classes and execution order

Tags: c#, architecture, unity-container, protocol-buffers

Microsoft's [Unity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647202.aspx) container allows to define concrete class and lifetime for an interface.

```
<register type="ILogger" mapTo="SerialPortLogger">
  <lifetime type="singleton" />
</register>
```

In caffe we can build Neural Nets with order of layers from text file [like](http://pastebin.com/KbZiwHn5).

```
name: "LogisticRegressionNet"
layers {
  name: "data"
  type: HDF5_DATA
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
...
}
layers {
  name: "fc1"
  type: INNER_PRODUCT
  bottom: "data"
  top: "fc1"
...
}
layers {
  name: "loss"
  type: SOFTMAX_LOSS
  bottom: "fc1"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "loss"
}
```

The construction order is effected by the order in text file and number of layers in text file.

How can i get extensible functionality in C# such that i am able to define mappings for interface as well as order of execution for program. e.g.

```
Initialize
Read
[Manipulate]
Display
```

will make program to do the said tasks unless manipulate is provided, then it will also manipulate.

I can do it with file handling etc. but is there a better solution than that?